# What is the benefit of mmap with MMAP_PRIVATE flag versus malloc

Tags: mmap

`malloc` will use `mmap` if this is beneficial.

What is the benefit of `mmap` with `MMAP_PRIVATE` flag and file instead of just use `malloc`?

Access to the memory is read / write.

From what I know, the only benefit would be that system will swap the memory into the file instead of system swapfile. This file may be on faster disk etc.

Any other reason someone may decide to use it this way?

Comment: You need to be a little bit more specific here. What are you mmap with here? Anonymous file? File with entry on the file system? Shared memory file?

Comment: map is map_private. so no sharing at all. asking theoretically. will edit to mention file is r/w

Comment: you can still mmap on a shared memory segment with MAP_PRIVATE giving you a private copy to work with, without affecting other users of that shared memory.

Comment: I see. but if two processes opens the same file with MMAP_PRIVATE and both begin to change it... and system runs out of memory wouldn't the system begin to swap and the file became a mess?

Comment: No, because the changes are not going to be written back to the source file. Basically what happens is, that for those pages where changes are made, the link to the underlying file system object is changed to an anonymous entry located in the disk I/O cache, which in turn is linked to the dedicated swap partitions / files.

Comment: On that note: Out-of-memory is one of those conditions where operating systems will begin to do crazy stuff. Like going around and "randomly" (well, not randomly, but often in the worst possible order) killing processes to make space.

Comment: yes I know, but I had no idea this is how MAP_PRIVATE works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the application. But one application may be mapping a shared memory segment (file), to which you want to make local modifications, without affecting the other users of that same shared memory. Thanks to *Copy-on-Write* only those pages of the memory segment that were actually altered need to be copied.